# Android Gradle two instrumentation test suites

Tags: android, testing, gradle

I am trying to set up a second instrumentation test suite for an android project. The project builds under Gradle and the ADT plugin.

I have `instrumentationTestSuiteA` and `instrumentationTestSuiteB`and `buildTypeA`and `buildTypeB`.

I would like `instrumentationTestSuiteA` to run on `buildTypeA`, and `instrumentationTestSuiteB` on `buildTypeB`.

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: I do not believe you can as there is only one option to set it in the `defaultConfig`. Did you resolve this?

Comment: I believe that the newer versions of the tools has solved this issue.

Comment: Can you make an answer?